# Find $k(2)$ and $k'(2)$ given the following information.

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Here is the problem, as well as my work and an attempt at a solution.

> [image]

**Did I do this problem correctly?** I was a little fuzzy as to where to use the f' value vs. the f value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work looks perfect to me. Nicely done.

I have one small recommendation, which is that you write the chain rule in the form
$$
(f \circ g)'(x) = f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)
$$
i.e., with the "derivative of the inside" on the right. Why? Because in a case like
$$
h(x) = \sin(\cos(x^2))
$$
the inside ($\cos(x^2)$ in this case) may itself be a composite function, and need to have the chain-rule applied. THe answer, in this case, is
\begin{align}
h'(x) 
&= \cos(\cos(x^2)) \cdot (\cos(x^2))' \\
&= \cos(\cos(x^2)) \cdot (-\sin(x^2)) \cdot (x^2)' \\
&= \cos(\cos(x^2)) \cdot (-\sin(x^2)) \cdot 2x 
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

here is another look at it. we are using the fact that $f(a+h)$ is approximated by $f(a) + f'(a) \times h$

$$ 2 \longrightarrow^g  \, 2 \, \longrightarrow^f-4 \\
   2 + 0.1\, \longrightarrow ^g\, 2 +5 \times 0.1 + \cdots  \longrightarrow^f-4+3\times 5 \times 0.1 + \cdots$$

the derivative of $f \circ g $ at $ x = 2$ is $3 \times 5 = 15.$

Comment: The problem with this answer is that $f(a+h)$ is also "approximated by" $f(a) + 2 f'(a) \times h$. You need to say that the error in the particular approximation you chose is $o(h^2)$; without that, you can't draw any real conclusion.